# Erro de SSL na integração sdk do Facebook com projeto no unity

Tags: unity3d, openssl

[image]

Erro que aparece no unity. Já tentei instalar o OpenSSL, mas ainda continua com erro.

Comment: Poderia postar um projeto mínimo em algum lugar (uma cena vazia com o mínimo de assets se possível) para que outras pessoas possam simular o seu erro e tentar descobrir a causa ou como corrigir? Além disso, qual é a versão do seu unity?